# Morgan and a String HackerRank challenge

Tags: python, strings, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

I am solving a HackerRank problem called **'[Morgan and a String](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/morgan-and-a-string/problem)'**.  Given two strings, each consisting of up to 10<sup>5</sup> uppercase characters, the task is to form the lexicographically smallest string from those letters by taking the first remaining character from either of the strings at each step.  Example, for input strings "ACA" and "BCF", the answer should be "ABCACF":

```
Jack    Daniel  Result
ACA     BCF
CA      BCF     A
CA      CF      AB
A       CF      ABC
A       CF      ABCA
        F       ABCAC
                ABCACF
```

Sample input, with one test case:

```
1
ACEG
BDFH
```

Output:

```
ABCDEFGH
```

I've solved it by writing my own code which works perfectly on smaller test cases. But when they run it against test cases which are approx 6000 characters long I get a runtime error. How can I increase the efficiency?

```python
n=int(input())#number of pairs to input
for mn in range(n):
    a=input()# String1 in the pair
    b=input()#String2 in the pair
    la=[]
    lb=[]

    for i in range(max(len(a),len(b))):#creating lists with all possible elements by slicing off the characters
        la.append(a[i:])
        lb.append(b[i:])

    if len(a)>len(b):#removes empty elements
        lb=[x for x in lb if x!='']
    else:
        la=[x for x in la if x!='']

    while True:#Create empty list for sorting the 0th elements of 'la' nd 'lb'
        temp=[]
        temp.append(la[0])
        temp.append(lb[0])
        temp=sorted(temp)
        print(temp[0][0],end='')#print the 1st character

        if(temp[0] in la):#removing the element after printing the first character
            la.pop(0)
        else:
            lb.pop(0)

        if len(la)==0:#breaks the while loop if a list gets empty
            print(temp[1],end='')
            break
        elif len(lb)==0:
            print(temp[1],end='')
            break
```

Comment: Your creating lists with all possible elements part takes too long on long inputs, code won´t even reach the rest.  [here](https://github.com/AnirudhGoel/Hackerrank/blob/master/Morgan%20and%20a%20String.cpp) is a c++ solution that you can translate to python.

Comment: @juvian - the first sentence of your comment sounds like a worthwhile review; consider posting that as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an improvement on [@Toby's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/203486/morgan-and-a-string-hackerrank-challenge/203529#203529)

1. Instead of `str += char` which allocates a new string you can yield the result and `"".join()` it later on
2. Here's the problem: consider `"BAB"`, `"BAC"`. One would think to compare the two strings, see that `BA->B` is more minimal than `BA->C`. or you see that `BA->B`(end of string) is shorter than `BA->(jump to other string)BA`. Both of these are wrong, because we end up with `BABBAC`, instead of `BABABC`, which is more minimal (`BABA < BABB`).

   The z fixes things because it fixes the issue where we incorrectly choose `BA->B\0` over `BA(first stack)->(other stack)BA`. `BA->BA < BA->Bz`. Realistically what we should do during tiebreakers is jump to the other stack when one ends so we are comparing against `BABB` instead of `BABz`, but the z solution is faster.
3. Normally with the `"z"` fix you need to remove them from the end result, but because *any* uppercase char is lower then the lowercase `"z"` we know after `len(a) + len(b) - 2` iterations only the 2 `"z"` strings remain in the resulting string. thus we only need to loop `len(a) + len(b) - 2` times

## Improved code

```
def morgan(a, b):
    a += "z"
    b += "z"
    for _ in range(len(a) + len(b) - 2):
        if a < b:
            yield a[0]
            a = a[1:]
        else:
            yield b[0]
            b = b[1:]

def morgan_and_string(a, b):
    """
    Return the lexicographically smallest string formed from the input strings, keeping each string
    in order in the result.

    Same length
    >>> morgan_and_string("ACEG", "BDFH")
    'ABCDEFGH'
    >>> morgan_and_string("ABCD", "ABCD")
    'AABBCCDD'

    Empty input
    >>> morgan_and_string("ABCD", "")
    'ABCD'
    >>> morgan_and_string("", "ABCD")
    'ABCD'

    Different length
    >>> morgan_and_string("Z", "ABCD")
    'ABCDZ'
    >>> morgan_and_string("ABCD", "Z")
    'ABCDZ'

    Descending strings
    >>> morgan_and_string("BA", "BA")
    'BABA'

    >>> morgan_and_string("ZAX", "ZAY")
    'ZAXZAY'
    >>> morgan_and_string("ZAY", "ZAX")
    'ZAXZAY'

    Proper prefix
    >>> morgan_and_string("BABC", "BA")
    'BABABC'
    >>> morgan_and_string("CABC", "CA")
    'CABCAC'
    >>> morgan_and_string("BAAC", "BA")
    'BAABAC'
    """
    return "".join(morgan(a, b))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Comment: Does this work with `("ZAX", "ZAY")` and `("ZAY", "ZAX")`, which should both result in `"ZAXZAY"`?

Comment: I read a comment in the discussion saying that we should add 'z' at end of both strings, but I didn't understand it. Can you please explain the purpose of adding it?

Comment: and please explain the reason that you took the range as `len(a)+len(b)-2`

Comment: @Sandesh.Patil I have edited a bit

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't understand it yet. How does this deal with the condition `a==b` ?

Comment: `a==b` was already handled

Answer (score 3):

**Code organisation**

At the moment, the logic handling the output/input and the logic computing the actual result are all mixed up.

This makes things hard to understand, hard to modify and hard to test.

It would be much easier to add a function with 2 parameters returning the string you are interested in.

With minimal changes, you'd get something like:

```
def get_smallest_string_combination(a, b):
    """Return the lexicographically smallest string ..."""
    la=[]
    lb=[]

    for i in range(max(len(a),len(b))):#creating lists with all possible elements by slicing off the characters
        la.append(a[i:])
        lb.append(b[i:])

    if len(a)>len(b):#removes empty elements
        lb=[x for x in lb if x!='']
    else:
        la=[x for x in la if x!='']

    output = []

    while True:#Create empty list for sorting the 0th elements of 'la' nd 'lb'
        temp=[]
        temp.append(la[0])
        temp.append(lb[0])
        temp=sorted(temp)
        output.append(temp[0][0])#add the 1st character

        if(temp[0] in la):#removing the element after printing the first character
            la.pop(0)
        else:
            lb.pop(0)

        if len(la)==0:#breaks the while loop if a list gets empty
            output.append(temp[1])
            break
        elif len(lb)==0:
            output.append(temp[1])
            break

    return "".join(output)

def automatic_test():
    assert get_smallest_string_combination("ACEG", "BDFH") == "ABCDEFGH"

def interactive_test():
    n=int(input())#number of pairs to input
    for mn in range(n):
        a=input()# String1 in the pair
        b=input()#String2 in the pair
        print(get_smallest_string_combination(a, b))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    automatic_test()
```

I took this chance to add a function testing the example you've provided.

Also, I've added the beginning of a docstring explaining the point of the function, I'll leave you finish it as an exercice.

**More tests and first bug**

Now that we have a simple way to write automatic tests, we could add test cases corresponding to edge-cases: empty string, string with one element, etc.

We'd get something like:

```
def automatic_test():
    # Same length
    assert get_smallest_string_combination("ACEG", "BDFH") == "ABCDEFGH"
    assert get_smallest_string_combination("ABCD", "ABCD") == "AABBCCDD"
    # Empty input
    assert get_smallest_string_combination("ABCD", "") == "ABCD"
    assert get_smallest_string_combination("", "ABCD") == "ABCD"
    # Different length
    assert get_smallest_string_combination("Z", "ABCD") == "ABCDZ"
    assert get_smallest_string_combination("ABCD", "Z") == "ABCDZ"
```

Which shows that empty inputs are not handled properly.

This can easily be fixed:

```
def get_smallest_string_combination(a, b):
    """Return the lexicographically smallest string ..."""
    la=[]
    lb=[]

    for i in range(max(len(a),len(b))):#creating lists with all possible elements by slicing off the characters
        la.append(a[i:])
        lb.append(b[i:])

    if len(a)>len(b):#removes empty elements
        lb=[x for x in lb if x!='']
    else:
        la=[x for x in la if x!='']

    output = []

    while la and lb:#Create empty list for sorting the 0th elements of 'la' nd 'lb'
        temp=[]
        temp.append(la[0])
        temp.append(lb[0])
        temp=sorted(temp)
        output.append(temp[0][0])#add the 1st character

        if(temp[0] in la):#removing the element after printing the first character
            la.pop(0)
        else:
            lb.pop(0)

    # Add remaining elements    
    if la:
        output.append(la[0])
    if lb:
        output.append(lb[0])
    return "".join(output)
```

**Logic and complexity**

The implementation is very complicated and inefficient but it would be much more simple.

At each step, you just need to compare the first character of each remaining string and add the smallest one (or both in case of equality).

**As discussed on the comments, this is very wrong. To be updated in the future...**

You'd get something like:

```
def get_smallest_string_combination(a, b):
    """Return the lexicographically smallest string ..."""
    la = list(a)
    lb = list(b)

    output = []

    while la and lb:
        first_a = la[0]
        first_b = lb[0]
        if first_a < first_b:
            output.append(first_a)
            la.pop(0)
        elif first_a > first_b:
            output.append(first_b)
            lb.pop(0)
        else:  # Equal
            output.append(first_a)
            output.append(first_b)
            la.pop(0)
            lb.pop(0)

    # Add remaining elements    
    output.extend(la)
    output.extend(lb)
    return "".join(output)
```

Comment: Is there any need to convert the strings to lists?  Python's not my strong language, but I thought we could do all the (final) version with string slicing.  Would that be better? Why / why not?

Comment: Oh, and we need to compare more of `a` and `b` if `first_a` is equal to `first_b`, as per the example in the question (that's unlike the merge step of a merge-sort, where we'd know the inputs were sorted).  So I'd suggest `if a < b: output.append(a[0]); a = a[1:]; else: output.append(b[0]); b = b[1:]` in the `while` loop.

Comment: Oh I might have missed something. I'd be most interested if you have an example...

Comment: Example: "BA" and "BA". Current code will produce "BBAA", but correct implementation should produce "BABA".

Comment: @cariehl, that's not my reading - we always need to read from the one that will give us the lexicographically-smallest result.  Order of inputs is irrelevant, so both of those should result in BABC.

Comment: @TobySpeight After re-reading, you are probably correct. In that case, if there is a tie, we should look-ahead to the next pair of chars (and if those are tied, the next pair after that, and so on) to find the path that will give us the lexicographically-smallest final result.

Comment: Oh Indeed, my code is wrong :-(

Comment: I wrote and tested my suggestion, and added that as a separate answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is a follow-on to [Josay's answer](/a/203492), and uses the same test suite.

We don't need to convert the two strings to lists; instead, we just need to pick the front character from the earlier of the two at each iteration (making sure that a proper substring of the other is correctly handled).  Then the function looks like this:

```
def get_smallest_string_combination(a, b):
    """Return the lexicographically smallest string ..."""

    output = ""

    while a and b:
        if a + b < b + a:
            output += a[0]
            a = a[1:]
        else:
            output += b[0]
            b = b[1:]
    return output + a + b
```

We can use the [`doctest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html) module to incorporate our test cases into the documentation:

```
def get_smallest_string_combination(a, b):
    """
    Return the lexicographically smallest string formed from the input strings, keeping each string
    in order in the result.

    Same length
    >>> get_smallest_string_combination("ACEG", "BDFH")
    'ABCDEFGH'
    >>> get_smallest_string_combination("ABCD", "ABCD")
    'AABBCCDD'

    Empty input
    >>> get_smallest_string_combination("ABCD", "")
    'ABCD'
    >>> get_smallest_string_combination("", "ABCD")
    'ABCD'

    Different length
    >>> get_smallest_string_combination("Z", "ABCD")
    'ABCDZ'
    >>> get_smallest_string_combination("ABCD", "Z")
    'ABCDZ'

    Descending strings
    >>> get_smallest_string_combination("BA", "BA")
    'BABA'

    Look-ahead
    >>> get_smallest_string_combination("ZAX", "ZAY")
    'ZAXZAY'
    >>> get_smallest_string_combination("ZAY", "ZAX")
    'ZAXZAY'

    Proper prefix
    >>> get_smallest_string_combination("BABC", "BA")
    'BABABC'
    >>> get_smallest_string_combination("CABC", "CA")
    'CABCAC'
    >>> get_smallest_string_combination("BAAC", "BA")
    'BAABAC'
    """

    output = ''
    while a and b:
        if a + b < b + a:
            output += a[0]
            a = a[1:]
        else:
            output += b[0]
            b = b[1:]
    return output + a + b

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Note that performance may be a concern, especially for longer inputs, as we create 4 new strings on every iteration (2 `+` operations before comparison, one string slice, and the append to output).  It may be worth implementing custom classes to provide views onto substrings and concatenations if the impacts are significant enough.

Comment: While this is better I think it can be improved some more... 1. instead of `+=` string operation which allocates new memory and is inefficient, you could `yield` and `"".join` the result. 2. Instead of assigning a new list `O(n)` with slicing `a = a[1:]` you could iterate over the index instead

Comment: That's string slicing, not list slicing; does that still involve allocation?  I wasn't sure how to use indexing and still compare the remainder of the string (other than tediously implementing char-by-char compare, and I'm too lazy for that!)

Comment: *any* slices are done slice-by-copy, meaning every time you slice it copies all of the data into a new string object.

Comment: "I wasn't sure how to use indexing and still compare the remainder of the string" I don't quite get what you mean here, I may have missed something... Does yours pass on hacker rank?

Comment: I've no idea about hacker rank (I'm not a member), but I've added a couple of extra tests to show the lookahead that's needed.

Comment: @Ludisposed Did you just delete your answer? I'll provide a testcase which I unlocked using hackos. https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/2335/input05.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ4WZFDFQTZRGO3QA&Expires=1536668551&Signature=L1AAIeX9HejoGqsKfq3AmsyPQb4%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain    This is one of the 13 testcases which I failed to pass. Maybe you could get some help with this!

Comment: @Sandesh.Patil Yes i deleted it, since the only performance gain i had was with the `join` but even then it still fails. Regerding the help... as stated in [help] broken code is off topic. If you do not pass all test cases it is not ready for review

Comment: @Ludisposed I tried to modify your code by adding `elif a[i]==b[j]` and tried to use recursion by calling `morgan(a,b)` in there. But I failed. Can you please try this one?

Comment: @Sandesh.Patil I passed check my answer

Comment: Ah, I see what I'm missing - new testcase and fix included.

Comment: @TobySpeight yes this is much more readable, only you create 2 new string objects for every iteration which is quite time consuming. Instead you could add `z` (only once) to the input strings

Comment: Yes, I was just investigating how to avoid copying with the string slicing and concatenation, but decided I was getting too deep here and just added a note.  Adding `z` on the end will suffice for English-only inputs, but less well for accented letters, so there's a caveat involved there, too (maybe we could use `'\xffff'` instead of `'z'`?).  I see that the linked challenge specifies that input is only ASCII `A`..`Z`, but that information isn't in the question!  :-(